# How do I rank/filter these records in a desired manner

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-server-2008-r2, ranking

Following is a sample data of the:-

```
emp doa
1   2014-01-01 00:00:00.000
1   2014-01-05 00:00:00.000
1   2014-01-08 00:00:00.000
1   2014-01-12 00:00:00.000
1   2014-01-15 00:00:00.000
2   2014-01-01 00:00:00.000
2   2014-01-05 00:00:00.000
2   2014-01-10 00:00:00.000
2   2014-01-12 00:00:00.000
2   2014-01-15 00:00:00.000
3   2014-01-01 00:00:00.000
3   2014-01-05 00:00:00.000
4   2014-01-10 00:00:00.000
4   2014-01-12 00:00:00.000
4   2014-01-15 00:00:00.000
```

> **doa** - Date of assigning a project

The requirement is to select the records which is closest to today - **giving higher preference to past dates** - which would indicate current assignment.

**The expected results are-**

```
emp doa
1   2014-01-08 00:00:00.000
2   2014-01-05 00:00:00.000
3   2014-01-05 00:00:00.000
4   2014-01-10 00:00:00.000
```

There are a few **restrictions** which I have:-

- The database (table) can't be changed - **normalization is out of question**.
- The actual data is huge - over 6 million records - **performance is must**.
- The actual data has some more fields (like payment per assignment, hours worked etc.) and hence **grouping can't be done either**.

The database is in **SQL Server 2008 R2**. Looking ahead for a solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If you need someone to write it for you, you should check with a contractor.  Questions here should include code and a detailed explanation of why it doesn't work for you.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more details.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code. You cannot directly ask for answers here. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: @Crontab/Mahe - I was really late in office and my intention was in no way to seek answer, but rather to seek help. Anyway, I had already tried ranking and then trying to implement some logic to filter correct ranks, also tried double ranking, partitioning the data based on date - one partition for data until today, second partition for future dates. I was still able to get the desired results, but the problem was performance. I'll not be able to post the actual code due to client confidentiality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a job for `row_number()`.  The hard part is getting the `order by` clause correct.  I think the following encapsulates the logic you are looking for:

```
select ed.*
from (select ed.*,
             row_number() over (partition by emp
                                order by (case when doa <= getdate() then 0 else 1 end),
                                         abs(datediff(day, doa, getdate()))
                               ) as seqnum
      from empdoa ed
     ) ed
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: +1, If you can just add the missing 'closing bracket' at the end of the `ABS` function, would be great

Comment: @Kiril . . . ouch!  done.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - Really like the idea of using the case to create a virtual tile for each employee. I'll definitely give this a try and check the performance, though I'm pretty confident that the performance of your idea would be within acceptable limits.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - The idea suggested by you worked - though i had to tweak a few things in order to get the performance up to the mark.